# System configuration verification tests/approach/tools

Tags: unit-testing, testing, configuration, verification, configuration-management

Question is about best practices for testing/verifying configuration of product.

Let's say we are developing hotel booking system, have 1 web site for taking books, background daemon job for processing bookings and API for communicating with hotels. Web site publishes messages to Message Queue, daemon consumes those messages, persists in database and sends notifications to hotels through API.

In this scenario, does it make sense to test/verify thing like:

- Web site has correct config files - pointing to right database, MQ etc.
- Message Queue has correct Exchanges/Queues
- Daemon has correct schedules
- API - correct client configurations etc.

Yes, smoke tests and integration test will test everything this, but they're more likely to do application logic testing. I want to have something which I can run before smoke tests, and for pre-prod and prod environment it will do great job checking all configs are pointing to prod ones.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is not really testing, this is monitoring.

You want to check the health of your system(s).

You'd start with monit (https://mmonit.com/monit/), as it's a very good base of running your daemons. Also it has built in, and scriptable checks, so if your daemon eats too much cpu or ram, it can restart it.

You can also monitor your mq server, and the length of the queues, to catch the problems as they arise.

For the config files and correct database connections: even your index page might fail if those are incorrect, so the monit like checks would diagnose these issues in seconds.

I'd also implement a health check in the application layer, and call that periodically from your monitoring service (like yoursite.com/healthreport.php, which is accessible only from a list of addresses). Then you can poll that. Be sure to give useful error messages with current version informations (like your app revision, php version or mysql version for example), and track these, because hunting a problem with no information is hard. (which server!? which user? which version is it? where is it? ohh did guys you just apt-get update?!?)

That way if your healthreport does not answer in time, and the answer is not "Everything ok", then it could send alerts to you.

For configuration I'd implement a three layer solution:
 - layer 1 is the default setting for everything, this is part of your source code, and it is version controlled of course.
 - layer 2 is a version controlled override configuration, that has only the differences to the defaults. You should have your installation entitys name in the config (or a hostname for example), so in one version controlled directory you could have the testing, production, development configurations stored. NO ONE EVER touches the configuration in production, you should always commit a change to do that.
 - layer 3 is the exception from the NEVER :) that is for security credentials, and that one is not ment to be version controlled, so it's just a file on the server near the installation, and that might hold the installation name too ("production" or "development" etc).

This layered configuration means you'll always know who changed what, you'll know which revision is out currently, and you can roll back any change (even automatically) if you're in trouble.

(except of credentials storage, but that hardly ever changes, and you do have backups of that don't you?)

Also logging, and log analyzing is part of your operations, your application should never hide problems (try catch everything), but it should have a built in exception handler, that logs every necessary detail about the problems, and helps you to track down the issue.

For example if your software is running in self hosted environment in a scripting language, you might deploy directly from version control software. And when an exception is raised, you can analyze the stacktrace (in realtime if you want), check in which file which line it happened, and use the vcs tools annotate feature to trace the last change to a developer, a revision (commit), and even to a ticket in your issue-tracking system based on the commit's message.

That way a smart system can:
 - notify the developer responsible for the last change in realtime (it's not always his/her fault, but he or she has the latest information, so they will be the fastest in tracing the problem to other developers if it's a must)
 - also if you've got an exception you'll probably get 200 of the same reason, so you can collect them together. (distinct DATE-sourcefile-line :) ).

Also you'd like to test these before going live? You'll need a staging environment then with nearly identical settings to the real one, and then you'll need a rolling update system to gradually release new versions. You could also automate this, that the rolling update goes on only when there's no known problems.

I'm sure that services like gmail track the response times too, so if a response takes 20% longer with the 2.1 version than the 2.0 version, they also count that as a failure, and the upgrade rollout stops even if users don't even notice the problem.

The basic idea is, that you should store all data before you try to process them (to be able to recover even if your system crashes), then you should store some metrics for profiling, have defensive written code to handle every possible failure scenario (test everything), and then automate the collection of these reports.

You also should build a client for your apis (it's nice to give that to your paying customers, to consume your api), and with that client you can monitor your services all day round.